# What will be the practical implications of trying EXWM in my macOS machine concerning the native macOS applications?

Tags: osx, exwm

I have been using a Macbook Air M1 for professional reasons and would like to amplify Emacs in my life.

I have been searching for the introduction of EXWM in my workflow. Unfortunately, as I started [reading the official documentation](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/ch11ng/exwm/wiki/Installation-on-macOS) I discovered that there are some limitations.

In particular:

> Note that EXWM cannot manage native macOS applications at all, only X11 applications will be managed.

This worries me. After following the instructions on [this source](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/tell-apps-optimized-for-m1-apple-silicon-macs/), I found some of the native macOS applications I have been currently using:

[image]

You can see important stuff for my workflow. Like, "zoom" (used for professional meetings). Or [karabiner-elements](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config) (heavily used by me to Emacsfy my macOS experience).

What are the practical implications of trying EXWM on my machine? For instance, will the Emacs hang?

Obs.: I was in doubt about opening this question here or in [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should move this to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Done, @NickD: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/453947/what-would-be-the-practical-implications-of-trying-exwm-emacs-window-manager-i